# Improper DataGrid Height Resizing with Text Wrapping

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, datagrid, wpfdatagrid

## The Problem

I have a `DataGrid`in a wpf application.
The problem has to do with how the `DataGrid` looks after certain window resizing events.
Whenever the user shrinks the window and then enlarges it again, the rows of the `DataGrid` shrink back down (because of the text wrapping), but the height of the `DataGrid` itself doesn't shrink.
The resulting effect is that there appears to be a border around the `DataGrid` that is too long.
This border shrinks back down as soon as the user decreases the height of the window. This border is also too long when the application is started.

## Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SampleApp.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="WrappingTextBlock" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WrappingTextBox" TargetType="TextBox">
            <Setter Property="TextWrapping" Value="Wrap"/>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>

    <Grid>
        <Border>
            <ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Objects}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="15" Width="Auto" Header="#" Binding="{Binding Number}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="65" Width="Auto" Header="Style" Binding="{Binding Style}"/>
                            <DataGridTextColumn MinWidth="80" Width="*" Header="Description" Binding="{Binding Description}" ElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBlock}" EditingElementStyle="{StaticResource WrappingTextBox}"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>                                      
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

## Code-Behind

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;

namespace SampleApp {
    public partial class MainWindow : Window {
        public MainWindow() {
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = new ViewModel();
        }
    }

    public class ViewModel {
        public ViewModel() {
            Objects = new List<MyObject>() {
                new MyObject() { Number=1, Style="Good Style", Description="Small description", },
                new MyObject() { Number=2, Style="Bad Style", Description="This is a medium length description that you are reading.", },
                new MyObject() { Number=3, Style="Awesome Style", Description="This is a long description that you are reading because I repeat the message. This is a long description that you are reading because I repeat the message.", },
            };
        }
        public List<MyObject> Objects { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyObject {
        public MyObject() { }
        public int Number { get; set; }
        public string Style { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: I had the same problem on cell height not coming back down.  I ended up going with ListView GridView and a lot of manual code.  Sorry I cannot post the code as it technically belongs to the customer.  What do you mean border is too long?

Comment: My cell height works correctly, I use `Width="Auto"` and `Width="*"` to fix that problem. My problem here is that the `DataGrid` itself doesn't resize correctly. When this happens, it looks as if the `DataGrid` has a `Border` around it that isn't sized properly (too long).

Comment: Does the issue still happen if you remove the StackPanel?  The StackPanel by default will give an infinite height to its children and this often causes sizing issues.  If the Orientation is set to horizontal then you would have an infinite width for children.

Comment: The `StackPanel` isn't cause for this problem (I tried removing it just in case). The `StackPanel` gives each `UIElement` as much vertical space as it needs but still displays them as if `VerticalAlignment=Top`. Actually, by taking the StackPanel away, the `DataGrid` would always take the size of the window (even worse than before).

Comment: Yes I have that same DataGrid sizing as a whole problem.  Like if I go into a Detail template and then close it down the DataGrid does not get space back.  That I don't have a fix to.

Answer (score 0):

Set the TextWrapping to Wrap for that column in your code behind after it's loaded. Worked for me.